# Store large binary in database(MySQL, PSQL, etc) using Spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to store large binary files in Databases such as MySQL, PSQL, etc in Spring boot. I have

I am using following type in DAO

```
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.BlobType")
@Column(name = "document", nullable = false, length=50000000)
private Blob document;
```

In PSQL, document column type is stored as **oid**
In MySQL, document column type is stored as **longblob**

I am trying to use following code for PSQL. Refer [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/binary-data.html)

```
LargeObjectManager lobj = conn.unwrap(org.postgresql.PGConnection.class).getLargeObjectAPI();
```

Is there any equivalent for **PGConnection** in MySQL?
Also Will MySQL supports **oid** type. I see it as **longblob**

Comment: Why are you using that code? Why not just store a `byte[]` and Hibernate will store it correctly. If you are using the `Blob` yourself you are basically defeating the purpose of an ORM.

Comment: And if you really want to use a `Blob` use the Hibernate `LobCreator` to construct it, don't resort to implementation specific code (hibernate already knows all of that).  Something like `Hibernate.createLobCreator(entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)).createBlob(inputStream, length);`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have used byte[] used select query with SessionFactory to fetch the data. I got whole document as stream when using resultSet.getBinaryStream(String) OR resultSet.getBinaryStream(int) instead of chunks. So I am trying with Blob

Comment: That won't change a thing when using a plain JDBC `ResultSet`. How you have mapped things in JPA doesn't influence how JDBC is going to return the result.